# getting null height for touchableOpacity

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi I am new to react native, I am following a course from udemy. In the course while creating a custom made button I am getting null height of the button but according to the course instructor the button should have height.

Below is the source code for App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Header, Button, Spinner } from './components/common';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

class App extends Component {

    state = { loggedIn: null };

    componentWillMount() {
        firebase.initializeApp({
            apiKey: 'AIzaSyB9AnPpTlaO5XbzPOhPPVBhCbn0SEel7hw',
            authDomain: 'authentication-ce600.firebaseapp.com',
            databaseURL: 'https://authentication-ce600.firebaseio.com',
            projectId: 'authentication-ce600',
            storageBucket: 'authentication-ce600.appspot.com',
            messagingSenderId: '979192009377'
        });

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user){
            this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
        }
        else{
            this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
        }
    });
}

renderContent (){
    switch (this.state.loggedIn) {

        case true:
            return (
                <Button>
                    Log Out
                </Button>
                );
        case false:
            return <LoginForm />;
        default: 
            return <Spinner size="large" />;
    }

}

    render (){
        return (
                <View>
                <Header headerText="Auth"/>
                    {this.renderContent()}
                </View>
            );
    }
};


export default App;
```

Below is the Button.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Button = ({onPress, children}) => {

    return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={styles.buttonStyle}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}> {children} </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
};

const styles = {
    buttonStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#007aff',
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5
    },
    textStyle: {
        fontSize: 16,
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        color: '#007aff',
        fontWeight: '600'
    }
};

export  {Button} ;
```

Here is what the expected output should be:
[image: this is the expected output according to the course instructor]

this is the actual ouput which I am getting:

[image: the blue line that you see is what all i am getting]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `<Header />` must have some height so it takes up all the space inside the parent `<View></View>` that's inside `app.js`. Now, since your `<TouchableOpacity>` inside `button.js` doesn't have any height (it only has flex). By just having flex it will take up the remaining available space and not take any height of  it's own. There is no available space for it since the parent `<View>` in app.js doesn't have height of it's own. The parent `<View>'`s height will be equal to the height of the `<Header>.` There will be no available space for the Button.

For a quick fix, inside your `button.js` just give some height to  `buttonStyle` like `200`. You can also give it some width.

You can also apply a height (More than  the header's height) to your parent `<View>` for this issue to go away.

Hope I've helped!

Comment: thanks...by adding height to <View> tag i am able to view the button but by hardcoding specific value wouldnt it mean that there will be different representation on different screensize. Can't there be anyway like bootstrap for web?

Comment: Correct observation. To make a responsive button you would need to use flex only. A general rule is to make the parent take up all the screen space and divide spaces among children using their own flex values. Another way would be to use height and width in terms of screen width and height. You can get screen dimensions using the Dimensions API in react native. Then set your button's height to say a third of your screen  height. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make slight change to Button.js to below

```
const Button = props => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress} style={styles.buttonStyle}>
    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{props.children}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

export default Button;
```

And in your App.js, you can pass those props as below to the Button component,

```
<Button
   onPress={() => {
     console.log('clicked');
   }}
   children={'Text Name'}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Header, Button, Spinner } from './components/common';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

class App extends Component {
  state = { loggedIn: null };

  componentWillMount (){
    firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: 'AIzaSyCnz8V-MuEiOWcs3oyBBxyO6BCjpAGJm7o',
        authDomain: 'react-native-auth-284c7.firebaseapp.com',
        databaseURL: 'https://react-native-auth-284c7.firebaseio.com',
        storageBucket: 'react-native-auth-284c7.appspot.com',
        messagingSenderId: '1049444233116'
    });


    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
      }
    });
  }

  renderContent() {
    switch (this.state.loggedIn) {
      case true:
        return <View style={styles.buttonContainerStyle}>
          <Button onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>
            Log Out
          </Button>
        </View>;
      case false:
        return <LoginForm />;
      default:
        return <Spinner size="large" />;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header headerText="Authentication" />
        {this.renderContent()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  buttonContainerStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 40
  }
};

export default App;
```

Copied this code from https://github.com/csjcode/react-native-auth/blob/master/src/App.js .This code worked for me